# Compare measure vs. true value: Methods and Visualization

Tags: data-visualization, error

I have a simulation routine that produces measurements of a continuous variable and I also know the true value. What is the optimal method to graphically depict, analyse and present the error or measurement? Any references, links, ideas, hints to the right direction are more than welcomed.

Comment: what is the dimension of said variable?

Comment: The variable has one dimension